# How can I embed Geb screenshots and HTML snapshot artifacts into renatoathaydes/spock-reports?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, geb, spock-reports

Is there a good way to embed Geb screenshots and HTML snapshot artifacts into the created [spock-report](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/spock-reports)? There does not seem to be an good solution to this outside of [geb-spock-reports](https://github.com/AOEpeople/geb-spock-reports), which is now deprecated.

Comment: Please edit this to be a question with a clear problem statement. Then feel free to answer it yourself, like you did. Remove the duplicate code, too. Presently, this is not a question and ought to be closed. For reference, you lately asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77284218/1082681).

Comment: FYI, I edited your "question" a little bit more to turn it from a statement into an actual question someone could answer. As for your original question, it was not closed and downvoted for no reason. The reason is given in the info for closing: _"Closed. This question is seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. It does not meet [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)."_ Did you notice that and read the guidelines?

Comment: Your new question suffers from a similar problem. It does not show what you tried. But at least, you have provided an answer (which you can actually accept to mark the question as answered), which is commendable and hopefully helps others, even though the question does not meet guidelines again. BTW, I did not downvote your original question, but I close-voted. As a newbie here, please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my solution I went ahead and made this code snippet shown below to do it in the `cleanup` step and using `reportInfo()`. This works well for me because I have a `SpecBase` class that gets inherited and used in all of the specs.

You can paste the methods and the code and add in your own paths and it should work. I'm aware this isn't the most elegant solution and can be improved or possibly added as a configuration option into this project, but for now here is a solution for those wanting the reports and failures to be embedded.

It basically finds the geb artifacts and moves them into the `spock-reports` directory to used the created html string which is inserted with `reportInfo()` for embedding.

I'm open to any suggestions to get this as a PR or to improve it. I haven't setup a test project to showcase this so unfortunately I don't have an example image to give just yet!

```groovy
    void cleanup() {
        def gebArtifactsPath = "build/reports/geb/path/to/specs/here/"
        File[] files = new File("$gebArtifactsPath$specificationContext.currentSpec.name").listFiles()

        insertReportArtifacts(files)
        insertFailureArtifacts(files)
    }

    /**
     * Finds all report artifacts taken. Moves them into the spock-report directory.
     * Then creates the html to insert into the reportInfo() which embeds them into the report
     *
     * @param files - geb artifacts from specs
     */
    def insertReportArtifacts(File[] files) {
        List<File> screenshots = files.findAll { !it.name.contains("failure.png") && it.name.contains(".png") }
        List<File> htmlSnapshots = files.findAll { !it.name.contains("failure.html") && it.name.contains(".html") }

        boolean reportFound = screenshots != null || htmlSnapshots != null
        if (reportFound) {
            def reportDir = new File('build/spock-reports')
            if (!reportDir.exists()) reportDir.mkdirs()

            htmlSnapshots.each { it.renameTo("$reportDir/$it.name") }
            screenshots.each { it.renameTo("$reportDir/$it.name") }

            def reportArtifactHtml = ""
            def screenshotIndex = 0

            htmlSnapshots.each { html ->
                def screenshot = screenshots[screenshotIndex]

                reportArtifactHtml += """                
                <table style="border:1px solid black;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>[Html Report] ${html.name.replace('.html', '')}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="${html.name}" target="_blank">html report</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>[Image Report] ${screenshot.name.replace('.png', '')}</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="${screenshot.name}" target="_blank"><img src="${screenshot.name}" width="400" height="400" align="center"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>    
                """
                screenshotIndex++
            }

            reportInfo(reportArtifactHtml)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds failure artifacts taken. Moves them into the spock-report directory.
     * Then creates the html to insert into the reportInfo() which embeds them into the report
     *
     * @param files - geb artifacts from specs
     */
    def insertFailureArtifacts(File[] files) {
        File screenshot = files.find { it.name.contains("failure.png") }
        File htmlSnapshot = files.find { it.name.contains("failure.html") }
        boolean failureFound = screenshot != null || htmlSnapshot != null

        if (failureFound) {
            def reportDir = new File('build/spock-reports')
            if (!reportDir.exists()) reportDir.mkdirs()

            htmlSnapshot.renameTo("$reportDir/$htmlSnapshot.name")
            screenshot.renameTo("$reportDir/$screenshot.name")

            def failureArtifactHtml = """                 
            <table style="border:1px solid black;">    
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>[Html Fail]</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>                
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="$htmlSnapshot.name" target="_blank">html failure</a></td>
                    </tr>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>[Image Fail]</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="$screenshot.name" target="_blank"><img src="$screenshot.name" width="400" height="400" align="center"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>                
            </table>"""

            reportInfo(failureArtifactHtml)
        }
    }
```